# Javascript Python for loop Syntax erros

Tags: javascript, python, loops

How does for loop work in Javascript? I have a couple Python code snippets I want to convert to JS to be ran online, but always getting Syntax errors.

```
final_words = [i.split()[-1] for i in chosen_stimuli]
```

I converted to JS as

```
final_words = [i.split().slice(-1)[0] in chosen_stimuli]
```

The second Python code I have is

```
for word in final_words:
    if word in ''.join(textbox.text).lower():
        matched_words.append(word)
```

I translated to JS as

```
for (word in final_words){
    if word in ''.join(textbox.text).toLowerCase(){
        matched_words.push(word)}
}
```

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` to convert a string to lower case.  It's unclear what you are trying to do with `''.join(textbox.text)` though

Comment: Your "JS" conversion doesn't work. JS doesn't have list comprehensions.

Comment: [transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/) can be used to convert Python to JavaScript (to run it in web browser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just convert python to javascript just by adding parentheses and braces randomly. It's about the actual concept of the code. Your snippet:

```py
final_words = [i.split()[-1] for i in chosen_stimuli]
```

Is using a list comprehension to map a function on a list. So, use `map` in js:

```js
let final_words = chosen_stimuli.map(i => i.split(/\s+/).slice(-1)[0]);
```

Your second code:

```py
for word in final_words:
    if word in ''.join(textbox.text).lower():
        matched_words.append(word)
```

Loops through a list, checks if a string contains a word, and if it does, append it to an array. So, do so:

```js
for (let word of final_words) {
    if (textbox.text.join("").toLowerCase().contains(word)) {
        matched_words.push(word);
    }
}
```

Note that JS uses `for...of` to loop through arrays, not `for...in`, which does something different.